# Question about Transfer at EWR from Terminal B to Terminal C with 6 check-in bag of luggage

Tags: customs-and-immigration, luggage, children, connecting-flights, ewr

I am flying from India to Newark (EWR) arriving at terminal B and then flying from Terminal C from Newark (EWR) to Houston. Both are separate ticket and i have to complete my immigration/custom at Terminal B.
Since i am flying with 2 kids what is my option to avoid moving luggage (6 check in bag + 3 carryon bag + 2 stroller) by myself from Terminal B to Terminal C to catch another flight ?

Comment: what airlines are you flying with?

Comment: Only one adult? Two kids in separate strollers? Have someone fly to EWR to help you or hire a VIP service at the airport.

Comment: How long between your inbound and outbound flights?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Hilmar, I have about 6 hrs gap between two flight.
Not sure if this is true but i came to know that after i complete my immigration/custom at Terminal B, There is Luggage Drop section so if i re-tag all bags from airline counter then i can go and drop it to luggage drop section at Terminal B where they will move it to my departing flight at terminal c and once that is done i can take either bus or train to go to terminal C with kids. Has anyone heard of this option ?

Comment: The luggage drop you mention is normally meant for people who are traveling on single tickets. Those travelers will have their bags already tagged through to their final destination and just need to pick them up, carry them through customs, and then drop them off at the bag drop. That won't work for you since you're on separate tickets and your bags will need to be retagged. It's possible that you'll find a rep of your airline (United, presumably) at the Terminal B bag drop who can check you in and issue you with new tags, but that's not guaranteed.

Comment: @user113831: you really need to call your ariline (United I guess) and ask. The luggage drop is typically reserved for people on a single ticket that have already checked in and whos luggage has already been tagged to the final destination. You need to do a full check for your second flight in Newark. Maybe you can check in online, use electronic boarding passes and have a United staff member in Terminal B tag your bags, but you really need to ask up front. Due to Covid a lot of the normal services in Newark are not operating, so online info is probably not reliable either,

Answer (score 5):

I go to EWR regularly but I don't recall seeing any porters in the last few year and I don't know if any are allowed in customs anyway. There are luggage carts but that won't help if you don't have enough hands to push it all.

Options

1. Contact the airline or the airport, see if they have any suggestion or ideas
2. Ask random strangers for help. Most people will be more than happy to give you a hand for some stretches of your adventure. Also ask, staff for help. If you need to take the train, ask an attendant to keep the door open until you have fully boarded or are out of the train.
3. Try to create your own porter. Bring a few 20-dollar bills and look for potential candidates. Maybe younger budget travelers that have more time then money. Ask for help getting to Terminal C and offer a 20 as a token of your gratitude.
4. Try to do it alone. If all your bags fit on one card and the kids can push their own stroller for a few minutes at a time this may work. Given that you have three carry ons, I assume the kids are all at least two years old.
5. Book a VIP transfer service. Maybe something like this https://murgencyairportassistance.com/ourservices?c=EWR . This is not going to be cheap.
6. Rebook your flight. This connection is a pretty bad idea, you'd be MUCH better of booking a single ticket with a connection outside the US and have Houston be your port of entry (it's a sizable international airport). I don't know how much time you have between connections, but given your situation, I would recommend AT LEAST 6 hours.